Question about replicates at different levels in a t-test
I'm a biotechnology master student. For an experiment, we wanted to know if there is a difference in the amount of bacteria grown at a certain temperature between two samples. So the setup is as follows:

We counted the bacteria that grew on a growth plate(yellow circle). So thats my data.
I took the mean of 2 duplicates for three dilutions. Then I calculated the mean of those three dilutions. Then I calculated the mean of those three replicates.
That's a singular number for a certain temperature (eg. 4°C) that I want to compare to the number of bacteria grown at a certain temperature of a different sample. Normally, I could do a student's T-test on the last three replicates, but since I take means of means, I'm not sure

I'd recommend that you read Molecular Biology of the Cell, 30: 1359 (2019) as an initial guide to statistical analysis as you continue your work in biotechnology. Your question raises a few issues that you need to consider.
The first is the distinction between biological and technical replicates. In your setup there's little question that the duplicates at each dilution within each of the 3 boxes are technical replicates, done to improve the estimate of the underlying response. At the other extreme, it's not so clear whether the 3 boxes represent biological or technical replicates.
From the above reference:

Treating technical replicates as biological replicates is called pseudoreplication and often produces low estimates of variance and erroneous test results. The difference between technical and biological replicates depends on how one defines the population of interest. For example, measurements on cells within one culture flask are considered to be technical replicates, and each culture flask to be a biological replicate, if the population is all cells of this type and variability between flasks is biologically important. But in another study, cell to cell variability might be of primary interest, and measurements on separate cells within a flask could be considered biological replicates as long as one is cautious about making inferences beyond the population in that flask. Typically, one considers biological replicates to be the most independent samples.

That's the first issue to consider.
The second issue is the nature of your outcome variable, a count value. Sometimes count outcomes come close enough to meeting the requirements for using a t-test or its extension into a linear regression model, but sometimes you need instead to use a Poisson or other generalized linear model that takes into account the limitation of counts to non-negative values and the way that the variance of count values changes with the number of counts. I think that's likely to be the case in your example, given that you are evaluating bacterial growth (colony counts?) at what seem to be different plating dilutions.
Third, in your particular example, it's not clear that averaging over all 3 dilutions is a good idea. That throws away a lot of potential information and makes the implicit assumption that all 3 dilutions contribute equally to an appropriate measure of bacterial growth. I suspect that your results are dominated by the values at the $10^{-2}$ dilution. You will probably be better off developing a model that takes the dilution directly into account.
To answer your specific question, there's no problem with combining technical replicates before you do further statistical analyses, if your focus is on biological variability. That way you don't have to worry about pseudo replication that comes from confusing technical variability with biological variability. The outstanding issue is how your technical replicates should be combined; the mean isn't always the best choice. For example, if your outcomes are colony counts on bacterial plates and you are using a Poisson generalized linear model, taking the sum of the technical replicates would respect the count nature of the outcome while maintaining the correct association between count value and count variance.

@jacala in addition to the excellent article linked above I recommend Stanley E. Lazic
Experimental Design for Laboratory Biologists.  The book has R code.  Lazic also has several papers on the topic
